# "Database Export" in Oracle SQL Developer via Automated Job

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way that I can create a job that will automatically perform the "Database Export" in Oracle SQL Developer.I need to perform this on weekly basis to keep a backup of all the database objects like tables and SP and index and sequences along with the data. Is there any other alternate way than manually performing Database Export.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer is a GUI.

So to schedule SQL Developer to execute one of it's GUI features, you need to make a command line call to SDSQL.exe - which is in the bin directory.

One of the options you have, is to call out to the EXPORT feature. But you'll need to use the CART to create an inventory of objects you want to export. Then you'll need to create a scenario/settings XML file for the export itself - that tells it what export options to use, where to write the file or files, etc.

Then you can use the OS scheduler (that Windows or *NIX) gives you to call SDSQL.exe.

[I talk about this process here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/11/scheduling-exports-of-your-data-using-the-cart/)

But.

This is NOT the way to do proper backups.

Use RMAN or DataPump to take a backup. Then use the database scheduler to kick off your database job to invoke rman or datapump.

The good news is that you can still use SQL Developer to help you setup rman and data pump export/backup jobs, and schedule them with the database.

Data Pump and RMAN items are on the DBA panel, which can be accessed via the View menu.

[image]